# Copy dovecot mail files from backup back into user's mailboxes

Tags: dovecot, mac-osx-server

My old server was cloned to a new machine, but all mails for a certain date range were not copied over.. If I look in each user's mailbox, all mail files for a certain date range are missing. I did find the files on a backup image however.

How can I copy the missing mails from the backup into each user's mailbox? Is there a *doveadm* command that can copy from one mailbox path to another? (I guess just copying the files is a bad idea.)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it what you're looking for?

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Move

Comment: seems like that is for mailboxes for users known to dovecot... I have a set of messages on a backup drive... they're not inside my dovecot mailboxes folder.

Comment: Well if your cloned image doesn't ship a full dovecot server, then your best bet is probably to copy the backup folders forceach user to a "restore" sub folder of their mailbox, reindex and let them cherry pick their missing content.